# How to Register multiple Service classes to Unity Container?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, unity-container

How to Register multiple Service classes to Unity Container?
I am using Unity.WebApi; My UnityConfig code is given below

```
var container = Container.Instance;

container.RegisterType<ILogger, Log4NetLogger>();
container.RegisterType<NHibernateFactory, NHibernateFactory>();
container.RegisterType<INhibernateUnitOfWork, NHUnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>();

container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(NHRepository<,>));

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

In the above code I have registered Product Service. Like that I wanted to register so many Service classes and Interfaces. If we add this manually then we have to add so many rows to register those classes.

Is there any solution to add this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

for your Service case..

```
container.RegisterTypes(
AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")),
WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
WithName.Default,
//this is important. Choose the one that suits you
WithLifetime.Hierarchical);
```